# Retrieving applications from app.config during debug

Tags: .net-3.5, app-config

I'm using VS 2008 with .NET 3.5, and I'm having trouble retrieving app settings when debugging. I've added a reference to System.Configuration and the console app compiles and runs, but when I try and retrieve an app setting, the return value is always null.

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="ConsoleApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <applicationSettings>
    <ConsoleApp.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="LogDirectory" serializeAs="String">
            <value>\c$\TestApp\LOG\</value>
        </setting>
    </ConsoleApp.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code snippet:

```
string logPath = @"\\" + machineName + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDirectory"];
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

EDIT: to clarify, that app.config XML was auto-generated. I added a new Application Configuration File item to the project, and then used the settings tab of the project properties window to add the LogDirectory setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use Properties?
You can access your properties using Properties.Settings.Default.WhatEverYouWant?

This is efficient and baked in Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you give a code example please? I've tried using "Properties.Settings.Default.LogDirectory" and I get a compilation error stating that "The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: This is your settings:
<applicationSettings>
        <ConsoleApplication2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="SettingName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>This a the value</value>
            </setting>
        </ConsoleApplication2.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>

You can acces it via Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName

Comment: Sorry the formatting of the XML portion didn't hold.  But the bottom line is to use : Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName

And BTW you have to go to your project Properties and Add A setting this will add an app.config file and the you will have access to the properties.

Comment: I encountered a minor problem because of a difference between the namespace of my project and the actual project name. Once I fixed that, your suggestion worked fine so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this - app settings is essentially a dictionary of strings.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LogDirectory" value="\c$\TestApp\LOG\"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx) for more info on app settings.